# Was Neymars transfer completely void even after committing to play until 2021?

Tags: football, fifa, uefa, transfer, la-liga

Is $262 million transfer completely void ?

Neymar had last year extended his contract until [2021](http://www.espn.in/football/barcelona/story/2977810/neymar-signs-new-five-year-barcelona-contract-until-2021) so is it really possible to break the contract.

If 'Yes' then why is there a contract in the first place?

If 'No' then were there any legal complications ?

Edit : I know the release clause amount was insanely undeniable, but there must be someone who had to respect the contract[either Barca or Neymar]

Comment: I'm downvoting here because this question is largely pointless, given that you know the release clause exists, and have completely ignored or not bothered to determine what a **release** clause will do for someone in a contract (very obviously: it involves being released).

Comment: @Nij yes thats your opinion and choice, anyways i got what i was looking for from philip that cleared it all for me...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is all completely valid. As part of Neymar's contact, both Neymar and Barcelona *agreed* to the value of the release clause - note that under Spanish law, *all* employees have a release clause in their contracts, and this applies just as much to footballers as to anyone else (for more details, see [this ESPN article](http://www.espn.co.uk/football/spanish-primera-division/15/blog/post/3172294/how-release-clauses-work-neymar-treated-like-any-spanish-worker)). PSG made an offer for Neymar which met the value in the release clause, so after Neymar paid Barcelona the appropriate fee, he was then free to move to PSG - and that's what he did.

Nobody has "broken" the contract here, as Spanish law mandates that any employee can release themselves from a contract - the only question is over the fee to be paid, and in Neymar's case, that was specified in the contract. There are no legal complications, because the lawyers who wrote the contract already thought about it.

(This ignores any possible question as to whether PSG will be in breach of UEFA's financial fair play rules due to their expenditure; that's a different question from the validity of Neymar's contract as it's between PSG and UEFA, not PSG, Neymar and Barcelona).

Comment: +1. You can think of it this way: the transfer fee includes compensation for the remaining time he would have played for Barcelona.

Comment: oh great! i dint know the fact that release clause is bound together with the contract, the thing that prompted me to ask this query was because barca refused to pay the loyalty bonus to neymar... which i found amusing even after a clean transfer...

Comment: @IteratioN7T The clue is in the name. The release _clause_ is a clause of the contract. And, presumably, they didn't pay the loyalty bonus because he was disloyal by leaving the club. Loyalty and legality are two different concepts.

Comment: @DavidRicherby With further reading, it actually turns out to be slightly more subtle than my first answer - release clauses are mandated by Spanish law; the two parties can either agree to a fee in the contract, or have it set by a tribunal.

Comment: @DavidRicherby true that... found an explanation to it [here](http://news.bbc.co.uk/sport1/hi/football/6314369.stm) that defines Loyalty bonus as: A player will get this for seeing out his contract at a club and it will be paid on the last game of the season in the final year of a contract. - So i guess Barcelona has the right to refuse.